# how to use for loop and if statement

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

The first problem is calculating the inverse matrix of (z-A） where z is a set of different complex numbers and A is a 2×2 matrix. 
The second problem is after computing the 2-norm of the set of inverse matrix, compare it with a certain number, how to write an if statement so that the set of z can be plotted on the graph with eigenvalues of A if the 2-norm of the inverse matrix of (z-A）is larger than this number.

I have tried to generate different complex numbers, and calculate the 2-norm.

```
A <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE)
ev <- eigen(A)
z <- complex(real = stats::rnorm(100), imaginary = stats::rnorm(100))
for (i in 1:100) {X <- solve(z-A)}
Y<- norm(X, "2")
a <- 0.1
if(Y > a){ }
```

The expect final graph should be a circle in the complex graph with its centre at (1,0), which is the eigenvalue of matrix A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code re-written

```
# use lapply to define X (also, note that in your loop you didn't have the indexing on z)
X <- lapply(1:100, function(k) solve(z[k]-A))
# let's check
X[[1]] %*% (z[1]-A)
# Almost equal to I_2 (small erorrs are normal)
#                            [,1]                        [,2]
# [1,] 1.000000e+00+0.000000e+00i -1.665335e-16+2.220446e-16i
# [2,] 1.110223e-16-2.220446e-16i  1.000000e+00-0.000000e+00i
Y <- sapply(1:100, function(k) norm(X[[k]], '2'))
# your a value (strange choice since all the Y's are > a)
a <- 0.1
# you can subset the Y's that are bigger than a like this
ind <- Y > a
Y[ind]
# and here are the corresponding z's
z[ind]
# and for plotting
plot(z[ind])
```

A few comments:

- You claimed the eigenvalues are `1;0`. My linear algebra is rusty and I haven't checked myself, but `R` seems to think the values are `1;1`
- As indicated above, your loop did not contain any indexing (I am assuming you meant to write `solve(z[i]-A)`. Also, `Y > 0.1` is `TRUE` for all `Y[k]`, so the choice `a <- 0.1` is a bit strange